# using curl in wampserver for Social engine

Tags: curl, wamp, wampserver, socialengine

I want to install Social Engine in wampserver but the massage "Curl extension is required" appears. What I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, PHP in Wamp Server is distributed with curl extension. you have only turn on this extension by doing these steps:

1. Click on the **Wamp server** icon in the notification area
2. Hover the **PHP** menu > hover the **PHP extensions** menu
3. Make sure that the **php_curl** line is **checked**

However, if your use PHP 5.3.13 or 5.4.3 with Wamp 64bit, the curl library may be broken, visit this page http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/ and download the right package for you then get the dll file.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) and setting the environment variable correctly.